# How to distribute rows to concurrent processes in the order defined on DB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, concurrency

I do have a DB table, which is kind of spool for performing tasks:

```
| id | status | owner | param1 |
+----+--------+-------+--------+
|  1 | used   | user1 | AAA1   |
|  2 | free   | user2 | AAA2   |
|  3 | free   | user1 | AAA3   |
|  4 | free   | user1 | AAA4   |
|  5 | free   | user3 | AAA2   |
```

This table is being access by many parallel processes, what would be the best way to assure, that each row from the table would be "used" just by single process but also at the same time given out in the same order as they are in table (sorted by `id` column value)?

---

My first idea was to simply mark always next row in queue with simple update:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET status = "used" 
WHERE owner = "userX" 
    AND status <> "used" 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1
```

and then fetch the marked row.

This was not performing at all - with some data (e.g. 3.000.000 rows) and bigger loads process list was full UPDATE statements and mysql crashed with "Out of sort memory" error...

---

So my next idea is doing following steps/queries:

**step1**

get the first unused row:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE owner = "userX"
    AND status = "free" 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1
```

**step2**

try to mark it as used if it is still free:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET status = "used" 
WHERE id = <id from SELECT above> 
    AND status = "free"
```

**step3**

go to **step1** if row was NOT updated (because some other process already used it) or go to **step4** if row was updated

**step4**

do the required work with successfully found row

---

The disadvantage is that on many concurrent processes there will be always a lot of jumping between steps `1.` and `2.` till each process finds its "own" row. So to be sure that system works stable - I would need to limit the number of tries each process does and risk that processes may reach the limit and find nothing while there are still entries in the table.

Maybe there is some better way to solve this problem?

P.S. everything is done at the moment with PHP+MySQL

Comment: Your first query seems the most straightforward (did you try adapting it to use `status='free'` instead of `status<>'used'`?). Do you need rows strictly to be selected in order, or is it acceptable if occasionally an earlier row is missed and a later row selected? (Not got any specific solution in mind, I just find that sometimes solutions are more forthcoming if the constraints are relaxed)

Comment: Are those resources different making sorting them compulsory in order to return the lowest id?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes, the order is very important, all entries should be "used" the in the same order as they were filled-in.

Comment: @Sleeperson: can you explain a little more what you mean, not sure if I'm understand your question...

Comment: was refering to same thing as Damien, if lowest available id should be awarded at all times

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, instead of sorting and limiting to 1 maybe just grab min(id):

```
SELECT MIN(id) 
FROM table 
WHERE owner = "userX"
    AND status = "free"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using a MySQL database to choose rows that need to be enqueued for lengthy processing, preferring to do them in the order of the primary index ID column, also using optimistic concurrency control as shown above (no transactions needed).  Thank you to @sleeperson for the answer using min(id), that is far superior to `order by / limit 1`.

I am posting one additional suggestion that allows for graceful restart.  I implemented the following that's done only at startup time:

**step0**

get lingering rows:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE owner = "userX"
    AND status = "used"
```

call **step4**

Etc. After a crash or other unwelcome (yet oh so common event) this will distribute out for processing the rows that should have been done previously, instead of leaving them marked 'used' in the database to trip me up later.